# mobile .css deceration, coming out of nowhere?

Tags: magento-1.9, css

I just upgrade to 1.9CC, here is the problem. my browser is looking for `skin/theme/css/mobile.css` I check my local.xml and also page.xml. it is not declare anywhere. I even add `<action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/mobile.css</name></action>` to my local.xml it still persist.  the most **STRANGE** thing is it dose **NOT EVEN DECLARE in my HTML** source file.  is anyone have the same problem? it really annoy the hell out of me. help?!

[image: 404 not found]

[image: not even in my html]

Answer (score 1):

Fresh downloaded magento CE 1.9.1, no sign of `mobile.css`. If it is not in the files, it is in the database.

Comment: what I don't understand, why there is a 404 error, if I didn't ask for it... in my final output html.  i search though the entire file folder... no string of mobile.css anywhere in the code.  if it is in the database, you know where to look to see code that output it?

Comment: hahaha never mind I found it, it's in one of my many @import scss.... -_- thanks anyway.